# RestWebservice test class, Insert records with wrapper HELP

Tags: apex

Hi Can someone guide me on how I can Complete my @httpPost class, I'm stuck at 26%. I don't have an idea on how I can insert a data if I'm using a wrapper for my parameters. Any help will do.

This is my Rest Webservice class

```
@restResource(urlMapping='/merchandise/*')
global with sharing class buyProduct{

    global with sharing class Wrapper1{

        public string CustomerNumber {get;set;}
        public List<Wrapper2> wrapper2 {get;set;}
    }
    global with sharing class Wrapper2{
        public decimal Quantity {get;set;}
        public string ProductCode{get;set;}
        public date StartDate;

    }

    global class ResponseWrapper{
        public String Status;
        public String Message;
        public String ErrorCode;
        public string CustomerNumber;
    }


    global static boolean isNotNullorEmpty(Object str) {
        return str != null || !String.isBlank(String.valueOf(str));
    }


    @httpPost
    global static List<ResponseWrapper> getID(Wrapper1 test){

        boolean selector = False;

          Map<String,Account> CNnumber = new Map<String,Account>();
        List<Account> accList = [Select Id, Customer_Number__c , Account_Credit__c from Account];

        for(Account acn : accList){
            CNnumber.put(acn.Customer_Number__c, acn);
        }

        List<ResponseWrapper> responseList = new List<ResponseWrapper>();

        Wrapper2 wrp = new Wrapper2();

        Map<String,Product__c> prdCode = new Map<String,Product__c>();

        List<Product__c> prd = [Select Id, ProductCode__c, Quantity__c, type__c, Price__c from Product__c];

        for(Product__c pc : prd){
            prdCode.put(pc.ProductCode__c, pc);
        }
        List<OrderProduct__c> opList = new List<OrderProduct__c>();
        for(Wrapper2 soW : test.wrapper2){
                 ResponseWrapper response = new ResponseWrapper();

            if(prdCode.get(soW.ProductCode) == null && soW.ProductCode !=null){
                response.Status = 'Error';
                response.Message = 'Invalid Product Code';
                response.ErrorCode = 'ERROR 400 : Bad Request';
                response.CustomerNumber = 'Invalid';
                responseList.add(response);
                selector = True;

            }     
            else if(soW.ProductCode == null){
                response.Status = 'Error';
                response.Message = 'Exception : Required field missing [Product Code]';
                response.ErrorCode = 'ERROR 400 : Bad Request';
                response.CustomerNumber = 'Invalid';
                responseList.add(response);
                 selector = True;
            }

            else if (soW.Quantity == null){
                response.Status = 'Error';
                response.Message = 'Exception : Required field missing [Quantity]';
                response.ErrorCode = 'ERROR 400 : Bad Request';
                response.CustomerNumber = 'Invalid';
                responseList.add(response);
                 selector = True;
            }

              else if(prdCode.get(soW.ProductCode).Quantity__c < soW.Quantity){
                response.Status = 'Error';
                response.Message = 'Not Enough Stock for your Order';
                response.ErrorCode = 'ERROR 400 : Bad Request';
                response.CustomerNumber = 'Invalid';
                responseList.add(response);
                   selector = True;
            }

            else if (prdCode.get(soW.ProductCode).type__c == 'Subscription' && soW.StartDate == null){
                 response.Status = 'Error';
                response.Message = 'Exception : Required field missing [Start Date  ]';
                response.ErrorCode = 'ERROR 400 : Bad Request';
                response.CustomerNumber = 'Invalid';
                responseList.add(response);
                 selector = True; 
            }

            //Validation for One time payment

             else if(soW.ProductCode != null && soW.Quantity != null){
                OrderProduct__c op = new OrderProduct__c();
                //op.Subscription_Order__c = so.Id;
                op.Subscription_Product__c = prdCode.get(soW.ProductCode).id;
                op.Quantity__c = soW.Quantity;
                op.Start_Date__c = soW.StartDate;
                if(prdCode.get(soW.ProductCode).Type__c == 'One Time Payment'){
                    op.Subscription__c = 'No';
                }

               Decimal totalPrice = prdCode.get(soW.ProductCode).Price__c * soW.Quantity;

               if(prdCode.get(soW.ProductCode).type__c == 'One Time Payment' && totalPrice > CNnumber.get(test.CustomerNumber).Account_Credit__c)   
                 {
                response.Status = 'Error';
                response.Message = 'insufficient  Credit for this type of Product';
                response.ErrorCode = 'ERROR 400 : Bad Request';
                response.CustomerNumber = 'Invalid';
                responseList.add(response);
                 selector = True; 
                    system.debug('#####' + response.Message);
                     system.debug('#####' + totalPrice);
                 }
                opList.add(op);
                 if(!Selector){
                response.Status = 'Products Bought';
                response.Message = 'Successful';
                response.CustomerNumber = test.CustomerNumber; 
                response.ErrorCode = 'Invalid';
                responseList.add(response);
                 }

            }
        }
        if(Selector){
            return responseList;
        }
        else{
             Subscription_Order__c so = new Subscription_Order__c();
             so.Account__c = CNnumber.get(test.CustomerNumber).id;
             insert so;
             System.debug('#####1' + so.Id);

            for(Wrapper2 sow : test.Wrapper2){

            Decimal totalPrice = prdCode.get(soW.ProductCode).Price__c * soW.Quantity;
            for(OrderProduct__c op : opList){
                op.Subscription_Order__c = so.Id;
                  Account acc = CNnumber.get(test.CustomerNumber);
                  system.debug('#####' + TotalPrice);
                  acc.account_credit__c =   acc.account_credit__c - totalPrice; 
                  update acc;
            }
            }

            insert opList;
            return responseList;
        }
    }

}
```

and this is the test class that i've written so far.

Can someone guide me on how I can insert a data to test using wrapper. Thanks in advance

```
@istest private class buyProductTest {

    /*
    static id createOrderProduct(){

    }
    */
    @istest static void insertOrderProduct(){


          Account accRecord1 = new Account();
        accRecord1.Name = 'Testing';
        accRecord1.Email__c = 'Testing@yahoo.com';
        accRecord1.BillingStreet = 'Testing Street';
        accRecord1.BillingCity = 'Testing City';
        accRecord1.BillingCountry = 'Testing Country';
        accRecord1.BillingPostalCode = '3021';
        accRecord1.Mobile_Number__c = '123456789';
        insert accRecord1;
        Account acc = [Select id,name,Customer_Number__c from Account where id = :accRecord1.Id];


        Subscription_Order__c so = new Subscription_Order__c();
        so.Account__c = accRecord1.Id;


        Product__c prd = new Product__c();
        prd.Name = 'Testing';
        prd.Price__c = 2900;
        prd.Quantity__c = 2;
        prd.ProductCode__c = 'test101';
        prd.Type__c = 'One Time Payment';   


        OrderProduct__c op = new OrderProduct__c();
        op.Subscription__c = 'Inactive';
        op.Start_Date__c = date.parse('20/02/2017');
        op.Quantity__c = 1;
        op.Subscription_Order__c = so.Id;
        op.Subscription_Product__c = prd.Id;



        List<BuyProduct.Wrapper2> Wrapper2List = new List<BuyProduct.Wrapper2>();

        buyProduct.Wrapper1 W1 = new buyProduct.Wrapper1();
        w1.CustomerNumber = acc.Customer_Number__c;
        w1.wrapper2 = Wrapper2list;
        System.debug('#####CustomerNumber' + acc.Customer_Number__c);

        buyProduct.Wrapper2 w2 = new buyProduct.Wrapper2();
        w2.Quantity = op.Quantity__c;
        w2.ProductCode = prd.ProductCode__c;
        w2.Startdate = op.Start_Date__c;

         String JsonMsg=JSON.serialize(w1);

        Test.startTest();

        RestRequest req = new RestRequest(); 
        RestResponse res = new RestResponse();

        req.requestURI = '/services/apexrest/merchandise';  //Request URL
    req.httpMethod = 'POST';//HTTP Request Type
    req.requestBody = Blob.valueof(JsonMsg);
    RestContext.request = req;
    RestContext.response= res;

        List<buyProduct.ResponseWrapper> response1 = new List<buyProduct.ResponseWrapper>();
        response1 = buyProduct.getID(W1);

        System.assert(response1 != null);
    }
}
```

Comment: I found something similar http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/84947/how-to-write-a-test-class-for-an-apex-class-with-do-post-method

Comment: @Reshma Updated my question. Can you help me on how I can insert a record using the wrappers that I instantiated. Any tip will do

Comment: Why do you need wrappers to insert records. You need to first insert records and then add them to wrapper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can test this just as you would test any other method by passing it an argument that you create from your test data:

```
Wrapper1 w1 = new Wrapper1();
w1.CustomerNumber = ...;
w1. wrapper2 = ...;
List<ResponseWrapper> responses = buyProduct.getID(w1);
// Assert number and content of responses here
```

(For your case, you are relying on the platform to do the deserialization and serialization and Salesforce take responsibility for testing that. So you only need to test your own Apex code.)

Before you go too much further, I suggest you rename the nested classes so they relate more to the domain you are working in i.e. get rid of the over-used "wrapper" term. That will help others understand your code better. And in particular the field name `wrapper2` will become part of your web service API and that will be strange for someone calling it.

Comment: I'd +1 again just for the recommendation to avoid smurf naming. Alas.

Comment: Hi @KeithC Followed your step on how I can instantiate the wrapper. Now my problem is inserting a record using those wrapper. Any tip will do.

Comment: @JMDF Do you mean "asserting" the wrapper content?